# Is there any literary name attributed to 12 verse length stanza?

Tags: british-english, poetry

Not a 12 line poem, but a 12 verse stanza.

Comment: verse and stanza are two different things.

Comment: Can you give an example? It's not clear what you mean by "12 verse stanza" - normally a stanza is not made up of verses.

Comment: A song stanza is a unit: one verse, one chorus, or one bridge. None are made up of the other. For A-A-B-A songs, you'd have two verses, one bridge, and a final verse = four stanzas. You need to clarify what is 12 verses.

Answer (score 3):

There isn't a set name for a 12-line stanza that serves as the counterpart of *quatrain* (4-line stanza) or *octet* (8-line stanza, often used to refer to first eight lines of a sonnet).

The closest you would get would be the French term *douzaine*, occasionally applied by scholars describing a specific medieval French stanza form. This term is highly specialized and not really used in English:

> One potential influence on stanza-length may be a twelve-line stanza popular in French literature from the twelfth century onwards and known either as the *douzaine* (for obvious reasons) or the *strophe helinandienne* [...] (Rhiannon Purdie, *[Anglicizing Romance: Tail Rhyme and Genre in Medieval English Literature](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Anglicising_Romance/nPwsFO6WXsAC?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=douzaine)*, 2008).

There are English poems with multiple twelve-line stanzas though, like the late 14th-century poem *[Pearl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearl_(poem))*. Critics commenting on these stanzas plainly call them **twelve-line stanzas** or use similar phrasing:

> [The second York play] is in **twelve-line stanzas**, of which the first eight are octosyllables, rhyming alternately, the last sixes maintaining the even rhyme but importing a new odd. (George Saintsbury, *[A History of English Prosody: From the Origins to Spenser](https://www.google.com/books/edition/A_History_of_English_Prosody_From_the_or/BNAEAQAAIAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=twelve)*, 1923).

> Fein, Susanna Greer. “[**Twelve-Line Stanza Forms** in Middle English and the Date of *Pearl*.](http://www.jstor.org/stable/3040975)” *Speculum*, vol. 72, no. 2, 1997, pp. 367–398. JSTOR.

Comment: Thank you very much! I realized my terminology was incorrect, saying "Verses" instead of just lines.